# Forward declare typename in template parameter list

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, typename, non-type

I have a function with the following signature:

```
template<typename Container, auto First = 0, auto Last = Container::size()>
doSomething(const Container& containter){...}
```

Is there a way which will allow the reordering of the template parameters, so I would be able to call the function like this:

```
doSomething<3,5>(someContainer);
```

Rather than have to do this:

```
doSomething<decltype(someContainer), 3,5>(someContainer);
```

This wouldn't be an issue, if I could move `someCountainer` after `Last`, however the default value of `Last` is derived from `Container`. Is there a way to forward declare `Container` within the template parameter list, or any functionality that would actually allow me to avoid having to add `decltype(...)` every time?

Comment: Are you sure that template arguments for `First` and `Last` are the correct choice here, instead of e.g. normal function arguments with default values?

Comment: @Evg because Last doesn't see Container?

Comment: yes, but you would need to remove the default values. also I don't believe `auto` is standard c++ in this context.

Comment: @lightxbulb, sure. :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes - it's a compile time loop inside this function (which requires compile time non-type variables).

Comment: @CruzJean It's c++17, you can use auto like that. Though in my original example I have `decltype(Container::size()) First`, but I decided to relax it, since if there's no solution to the relaxed problem, then there won't be a solution to the one with the `decltype` is what I figured.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is overloading:

```
template<auto First, auto Last, typename Container>
void doSomething(const Container& containter);

template<auto First, typename Container>
void doSomething(const Container& containter) {
    doSomething<First, Container::size()>(containter);
}

template<typename Container>
void doSomething(const Container& containter) {
    doSomething<0, Container::size()>(containter);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

And another one, though not that elegant, is to use a sentinel value for `Last`:

```
template<auto F = 0, auto L = -1, typename Container, 
    typename Container::size_type First = F, 
    typename Container::size_type Last = (L == -1) ? Container::size() : L>
void do_something(const Container& containter)
{}
```